# Why is my character not jumping but is receiving input?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi I was wondering why my character is not jumping all tho is shows that it is receiving input (I am using the character controller component) all help is appreciated!

Code:

```
public class Player_movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController controller;
    public float speed = 12f;
    Vector3 velocity;
    public float gravity = -9.85f;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float groundDistance = 0.4f;
    public LayerMask groundMask;
    bool isGrounded;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);

        if(isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
        {
            velocity.y = -2f;
        }

        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
        {
            velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * gravity);
        }

        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;
        controller.Move(move * speed *Time.deltaTime);

        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Again as I said it is receiving the input but my character is not jumping.

Comment: What is the change in velocity do you actaully apply? Is it even positive? Is it countered by the simulated gravity?

Comment: What is `jumpHeight` ? It doesn't exist in the code you posted ...

Comment: try to debug your code and then ask perephased question

Answer (score 0):

You probably need your character's ground check sphere to get out of collision before the "jumping" simulation can begin. Otherwise it will keep reverting velocity.